# No component for supporting the service HomeController was found - Castle Windsor error

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

I read [this](https://gist.github.com/martinnormark/3128275#file_controllers_installer.cs) article about Casle Windsor. So I have classes BusinessLogicInstaller.cs, ControllersInstaller, IocContainer and WindsorControllerFactory. Here is the example:

```
public class ControllersInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.Register(AllTypes.FromThisAssembly()
            .Pick().If(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Controller"))
            .Configure(configurer => configurer.Named(configurer.Implementation.Name))
            .LifestylePerWebRequest());
    }
}

public class BusinessLogicInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.Register(
            Component
            .For<IUser>()
            .ImplementedBy<User>());
    }
}

public static class IocContainer
{
    private static IWindsorContainer _container;

    public static void Setup()
    {
        _container = new WindsorContainer().Install(FromAssembly.This());

        WindsorControllerFactory controllerFactory = new WindsorControllerFactory(_container.Kernel);
        ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(controllerFactory);
    }
}

public class WindsorControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    private readonly IKernel _kernel;

    public WindsorControllerFactory(IKernel kernel)
    {
        this._kernel = kernel;
    }

    public override void ReleaseController(IController controller)
    {
        _kernel.ReleaseComponent(controller);
    }

    protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
    {
        if (controllerType == null)
        {
            throw new HttpException(404, string.Format("The controller for path '{0}' could not be found.", requestContext.HttpContext.Request.Path));
        }
        return (IController)_kernel.Resolve(controllerType);
    }
}
```

In the Global.asax class I have

```
public class MvcApplication : HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

        // Add this line to Application_Start in Global.asax.cs to setup the IoC Container.
        IocContainer.Setup();
    }
}
```

The problem is in class WindsorControllerFactory.cs in this line of code:

```
return (IController)_kernel.Resolve(controllerType);
```

The error is No component for supporting the service Controllers.HomeController was found. Where is the error?

Comment: Cannot reproduce, works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution... First of all, I didn't mention one big difference in my MVC project(because I didn't know why is that important) - I have separate assembly for Controllers. So, there was an error in this part of the code in `ControllerInstallers.cs` :

```
.FromThisAssembly()
```

It should be:

```
.FromAssemblyNamed("Controllers")
```

I have to say thank you to @Jan Muncinsky because of your answer and because of your hint to a class where the problem was.